# Localizations or quotients of categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory

**Motivation:** In the classical construction of the derived category of an abelian category, one (roughly) starts with an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, then considers the *quotient* category $\mathcal{K}$ of $\mathcal{A}$-chain complexes modulo homotopy and observes this is triangulated; finally, the derived category $\mathcal{D}$ is the localization of the above triangulated category with respect to some morphisms defined in terms of the triangulated structure.

I have always thought as the first process of modding out by homotopy equivalences as being a way to make homotopy-equivalent maps look the same or *inverting things which are homotopy equivalent to invertible arrows*. Then realized that this is also the aim of localising: force some arrows to become isomorphisms.

Here the **question:** is there a conceptual frame in which we can see both localisation and modding out by a relation as special cases? Or, are the two concepts better related that my vague interpretation that they both make some arrows invertible? I have seen someone in nLab saying that they are *entirely different constructions* but that left me a bit disappointed since I still believe a bit in the feeling that at the end of both days I find myself with a new category having the same objects as the old one, and some new isomorphisms. More generally: I realise that if I had a category in my hands and were willing to see some arrows become isomorphisms, I would not know which of the two approaches would be natural in my case, whence the feeling I still have some fog in my mind.

I should add that a colleague of mine observed that he would expect the first construction to be reminiscent of taking closed immersions, and the second to open immersions; which I fully agree to, but would again like to know how to think about these parallels when dealing with a category.

Comment: Sure. They're both colimits. (I mean, it's not as if you're trying to compare a limit and a colimit. Localizations and quotients both have universal properties involving maps out rather than maps in, so saying *entirely* unrelated seems a bit unfair to me.)

Comment: In your specific example, $\mathcal{K}$ is actually isomorphic to the localisation of $\mathbf{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$ with respect to chain homotopy equivalences. This is true more generally when you have suitable cylinder objects or path objects.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Uhm... could you explain a bit more? In which world are you considering this colimit(s)? They are objects having universal properties "out" but as Categories, so you are working in __$Cat$__ or something?

Comment: @Filippo: yes. More specifically, localizing a category by inverting some collection of morphisms can be described as a pushout in $\text{Cat}$, and quotienting a category by an equivalence relation on morphisms can be described as a coequalizer in $\text{Cat}$ (I think).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are completely different constructions which are in general absolutely unrelated but might coincide on some rare occasion. the image of closed immersion vs open immersion is quite good I think, especially if you think about it in terme of localization of a ring: it might happen that localizing a ring is the same as taking a quotient, but this is rather exceptional...

(Edit: this being said, I totally agree with Qiaochu Yuan comments and "absolutely unrelated" was slightly exaggerated )

The reason why they give the same things in a lot of example (including chain complexes), giving the idea that they should be related, is because these examples are Quillen model categories and that it is the main result of Quillen's "Homotopical Algebra" (where he defined model categories) that for Quillen model category the localization by weak equialence can be constructed as a quotient of the full subcategory of fibrant-cofibrant objects.

Edit for References: The orginal paper of Quillen ([Homotopical algebra](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0097438)) is actually a really good reference on the subject, which give both the general theory and the examples of simplicial sets and of chain complex.
There has been also several book on the subject, I would advise to take a look to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_category) which contains already most of the relevant information as well as references to the main books on the subject.

Comment: For a finitely generated algebra, it might seem odd to have localization and quotients coincide, but consider the case $R[x_i\mid i\in\mathbb N]$, i.e. you have infinitely many variables. Localizing in some polynomial $f$ is the same as picking a variable $x_i$ that does not appear in $f$ and taking the quotient by $x_if-1$. This was my initial thought when I saw the question: Maybe categories are so "large" that quotients and localizations could coincide more easily.

Comment: I'm not completely agreeing with your remarks for the following reason: the two constructions you are giving indeed give the same ring, but in the case of a quotient or a localization of a ring $R$, what is important is not the ring, but the $R$-algebra you obtain (the universal property you obtain involve the $R$-algebra structure) and in your situation, the two $R[(x_i)]$ algebras are not isomorphic.

Comment: In contrast, in the case of model categories (and in the example of chain complex mentioned in the question), the identification of the localization with a quotient is essentially compatible with the functor from the initial category (more precisely: at least when you restrict to fibrant-cofibrant object).

Comment: That's a good point and an interesting additional piece of information =), thanks.

Comment: The way I see the difference in the categorical context can be formulated as follows. In any case, **identifying** certain objects is not natural; one may speak about forcing non-isomorphic objects to become isomorphic. Now the latter can be achieved in two different ways - either by turning certain morphisms between them into isomorphisms, or adding completely new isomorphisms. The former is more on the quotient side and the latter more on the localization side...

Comment: The terme "quotient" is used here for quotient of a category by an equivalence relation on morphisms. Not for trying to identify object.

Comment: @SimonHenry: Thanks, but I must confess I am totally ignorant about model categories, so it would be helpful if you could add a couple of details/references...

Comment: I added references. For the details, the wikipedia page is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, Quillen indeed ciotains the answer I was looking for. As an aisde, do you have any idea of occurrencies of "moding out homs by relations" which has nothing to do with localizations, as you say at the very beginning of your answer?

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo, consider an antisimmetric category (so that for distinct objects $x$ and $y$ at most one of the sets $\hom(x,y)$ and $\hom(y,x)$ is nonempty,and there are no nonidentity endomorphisms) and consider the equivalence relation which identifies all elements in each nonempty $\hom$ set. This is not a lozalization, because there are no isomrphisms in the resulting category.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: ok, I see. Although already not bad (and in any case more than I could have done), can you think of an "explicit" example which occurs somewhere (or an application of yours)?

Comment: Well, it has been ore or less already mentioned, but if you take a ring $R$, you can see it as a one object pre-additive category. A localization of $R$ is a localization of the corresponding category, a quotient of R is a quotient of the corresponding category. And there are quotients of ring which are not localizations (localization are always flat, while quotient of ring are almost never flat). This generalize to arbitrary additive/abelian category.

Answer (score 6):

The term you're looking for is 'coinverter' (dual of the notion of [inverter](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inverter)). This is a [weighted colimit](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit) in the $Cat$-enriched category $Cat$. See [this page on the nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localization#general).

Comment: I tried to follow the link, but it seems to me thatit only describes localizations and I find no reference to quotients.

Comment: One can take quotients of categories to calculate localisations in certain cases. For instance (the following may be roughly right) when one takes the fibrant and cofibrant objects in a model category with a cylinder object, then taking the quotient of the full subcategory by the relation of homotopy gives the localisation at the weak equivalences. This is a serious theorem of Quillen, and showed that localisations of model categories are locally small. Chain complexes have a model structure with weak equivalences the quasi-isomorphisms (and this was one of the motivating examples for Quillen)

Comment: You might want to look at Quillen's monograph _Homotopical Algebra_ http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0097438, if you have access.