# Verdier Quotient a quotient?

Tags: ct.category-theory, localization

This question seems trivial, so hopefully it will be resolved quickly.

As pointed out in [this question on quotient categories and localization,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188193/localizations-or-quotients-of-categories) the two constructions are sometimes related, but in general quite different.

Let $C$ be a triangulated subcategory of a triangulated category $D$, and let $$Q: D \to D/C$$
be the Verdier quotient. As I understand it, to show the existence of such a quotient, Verdier constructed it as a localization (see [the proof in these notes](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/john.pdf), for example). But it is still referred to as the Verdier quotient.

My question is
Is the Verdier quotient category $D/C$ actually a quotient category of $D$, say in the sense of [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_category)?

The motivation of this question is that I am looking at a particular Verdier quotient and I want to understand certain properties of the hom-sets, and it would be easier (for me) to think about a quotient, rather than a localization for this.

Comment: My understanding is that the Verdier quotient is an example of cofiber (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_%28topology%29 ), which is a sort of "homotopy quotient". I am skeptical that the notion of "quotient category" is related in general (although it might well coincide in some special cases)

Comment: No, it's not a quotient in Wikipedia's sense. Consider the derived category as the Verdier quotient of the homotopy category by acyclic complexes.

Comment: The sense in which Verdier quotients are quotients is that you are trying to identify some objects (not morphisms), namely you are trying to identify a bunch of objects with $0$. Wikipedia's notion of quotient category is only about identifying morphisms.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @DenisNardin this can actually be made precise: https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08287